# Keeping default values for nested named parameters

Tags: default-value, raku, rakudo

I suspect that this question is very easy to answer, and that the answer is "no".  However, I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Consider the following code:

```
sub f(:$a = 'foo') { say $a }
sub g(:$a) { f :$a }
g();  # OUTPUT: «(Any)»
```

Is there a good way to change the signature/body of `&f` or `&g` so that this prints `foo` instead of `Any`?

I know of two ways to get `&f` to use the default value for `$a`, but neither of them are great.

Option 1:

```
sub f(:$a = 'foo') { say $a }
multi g(:$a) { f :$a }
multi g()    { f }
g();  # OUTPUT: «foo»
```

Option 2:

```
sub f(:$a = 'foo') { say $a }
sub g(:$a) { f |(:$a with $a) }
g();  # OUTPUT: «foo»
```

Neither of these feel like *great* approaches, so I'm hoping that someone can show me a more elegant approach that I'm missing.  On the other hand, these both work, so it certainly won't be a big deal if this is just a slightly inelegant corner (and a very small one).

Comment: If I run your first example I get an error, not `(Any)`

Comment: Yeah, g() passes a positional to f(), **not** a named argument.  UPDATE: fixed example

Comment: Thanks to you both.  Yes, that fix was what I intended; apologies for the typo.

Comment: I don't think it matters, because I think Liz has nailed it -- at least, her answer is the one I was about to write -- but the first example still doesn't work but instead says `Cannot unbox a type object (Any) to a str.`

Comment: Thanks, @raiph – clearly I shouldn't rush to post a question before going afk!  I've removed the native type contraints

Comment: No disrespect to anyone who posted an answer, but I find option 2 `sub g(:$a) { f |(:$a with $a) }` very readable. Below, I find myself doing a double-take when I read `g a => "bar";  g;` . No offense, @ElizabethMattijsen !

Comment: @jubilatious1 none taken  :-)  The "problem" I have with option 2, is that it unnecessarily topicalizes `$_`,  `|(:$a if $a.defined)` wouldn't  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use either option 1, or if sub "g" always just calls sub "f", to create a capture of *all* parameters, and just pass that on:

```
sub f(str :$a = 'foo') { say $a }
sub g(|c) { f |c }
g a => "bar";  # "bar"
g;             # "foo"
```

Comment: The passing on of the capture is something I've done a few times and it feels… weird because AFAICT the arguments are getting unpacked in the slip and repacked for the call.  Or can the compiler catch `sub foo(|c) { bar |c }` to pass the capture through seamlessly?

Comment: My guess has always been... `|c` in a parameter list binds the symbol `c` to a fresh capture built from the remaining part of the incoming capture that has not yet been removed by the signature processing prior to the `|c`. If the `|c` is right at the start of the signature, the compiler just binds to the original capture. Similarly, `|c` in an argument list does the logical inverse, notionally slipping the `c` capture into a new capture being constructed for the call, but, again, presumably just using the capture directly as is if there's nothing else in the argument list.

Comment: @raiph That's certainly what I'd hope would be the (optimal) case, but I wasn't sure if it was actually happening or not. For what I was doing, there wasn't any real alternative so I didn't give it much more thought, this just reminded me of it

Comment: Mind you, if sub g just alwyas calls sub f, then maybe `my constant &g = &f;` would be a better solution. :-)

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen iirc I used this for a subclass of a Hash, for which BUILD and TWEAK aren't called. So my new was `method new (|c) { self.bless!build: |c }` where the build method returned self at the end. It was a bit clunky but worked

Comment: Interesting...  hmmm...that could be considered a bug?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I'd need to go find where I reference it in my documentation, but I remember linking to an issue on the topic where it was noted that that was by design for some reason I now forget.

Comment: @user0721090601 "I used this for a subclass of a Hash, for which BUILD and TWEAK aren't called." That sounds weird. `class A { submethod TWEAK { say 42 } }; class B is A {}; B.new; # 42`.

Comment: @raiph: try `class A is Hash { submethod TWEAK { say 42 };  submethod BUILD { say 24 } }; A.new`  It's specific to `Hash` (and a handful of few other classes).