# Interpolate without creating a String context in Raku?

Tags: string, raku, string-interpolation, rakudo

If I have a variable `my $a = True`, then I get this output from the following code:

```
say «a list of words foo $a bar baz».raku; 
# OUTPUT: ("a", "list", "of", "words", "foo", "True", "bar", "baz")
```

That is, even though the result is a `List`, the element `True` is stringified before being included in the list – the list contains `"True"`, not `True`.  Is there any way to avoid that stringification while still using interpolation?

Would there be a way to do so if `$a` were a class I'd defined (and thus can write the `Str` method for) rather than a `Bool`?

(I am aware that I can write the more verbose `("a", "list", "of", "words", "foo", $a, "bar", "baz")` or `«a list of words foo».Slip, $a, «bar baz».Slip`, but I'm asking if there is a way to still use interpolation).

Comment: I have two reasons for asking this question even though I believe that the answer is "no, that's not possible".  First, I might be wrong – as has [happened before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66555706) when I thought Raku couldn't do something.  Second, having SO answers that say "that's impossible" could save other users the trouble of searching for the correct syntax to do something that will never work.  (And listing things that Raku can't do is a poor fit for the docs.)  Please let me know if you find this sort of question annoying; if not, I may ask a few in the next several days.

Comment: "when I thought Raku couldn't do something." Raku can't alter the laws of physics, but short of that no PL can do more than Raku can. It contains a Turing complete GPL. The only constraints are things like when, how efficiently, and how easily it does what it does. Raku supports [MSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_programming), so Raku can do it at compile time, whatever "it" is. Standard Raku already ships with features making some MSP tasks easy. RakuAST, and tools built atop it, will make essentially all MSP tasks a lot eas*ier*, including MSP for both sweetness and performance.

Comment: "Please let me know if you find this sort of question annoying; if not, I may ask a few in the next several days." I think a hundred of your thoughtful Qs about this would be a wonderful thing, though I urge you to spread them out, waiting until a Q you've posted has gotten an answer you've accepted, or at least N days have passed (where N=2 feels about right) without an accepted answer, before posting the next one.

Comment: "I urge you to spread them out, waiting until a Q you've posted has gotten an answer you've accepted, or at least N days have passed (where N=2 feels about right) without an accepted answer, before posting the next one."  Agreed 100%

Comment: > "no PL can do more than Raku can. It contains a Turing complete GPL."  I mean, that's _technically_ correct.  But for fairly reasonable meanings of "Raku" and "can't do", I'd say there are hings that Raku currently can't do (though many more that it can!).  For example, "Raku" currently "can't" know that `sub f(--> Int) { 'Oops' }` is invalid at compile time.  I don't mean that it's impossible to write a static analyzer for Raku; obviously it's not.  And I don't mean that Raku will never be able to do so.  I just mean that, right now, [it can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484454).

Comment: .@codesections Sure. Though right now you could write `BEGIN { f }` and the result is a compile-time error. To be clear, I got, and get, what you were, and are, saying. My comment wasn't addressed to you personally but was primarily for later readers that might misinterpret what can and can't be done. Some PLs will *never* be able to empower devs to timeshift stuff from run-time to compile-time, but Raku already does, and more is coming. As you say, devs can write a static analyzer, and, as jnthn noted, part of the near term roadmap is making it possible to implement type checkers as modules.

Comment: Is this really an 'early' versus 'late' question? You might imagine in some languages that interpolation gets delayed (however maybe not within the context of the method chain example you've presented). But there indeed maybe other languages that (for example) detect a Boolean or `NA` value and preserve it as is (i.e. don't stringify during interpolation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interpolation is putting a thing into a string.

```
"a b c $thing d e f"
```

It does that by first turning the thing itself into a string, and concatenating the rest of the string around it.

Basically the above compiles into this code:

```
infix:<~>( ｢a b c ｣, $thing.Str, ｢ d e f｣ )
```

---

```
« a b c $thing »
```

Is short for:

```
Q :double :quotewords « a b c $thing d e f »
```

That is use the `Q`uoting DSL, turning on `:double` quote semantics (`“”`) and turning on `:quotewords`.

`:quotewords` is the feature which splits the string into its individual parts.
It happens only after it has been turned into a string.

Imagine that the above compiles into:

```
Internals::quotewords( infix:<~>( ｢ a b c ｣, $thing.Str, ｢ d e f ｣ ) )
```

---

There is another way to get what you want, other than using `.Slip` or prefix `|`.

```
flat «a list of words foo», $a, «bar baz»
```

---

The whole purpose of the quoting DSL is that it produces a string.

That said `:words`, `:quotewords`, and `:val` all change it so that it returns something other than a single string.
And the idea of them is that they alter the DSL.

So **MAYBE** you could convince enough people that such a change would be worth it.
Thats a big *maybe*.

It would potentially break many existing codebases, so you would have an uphill battle to do so.

Comment: Or, even better, just create a specialized DSL ^_^  (which reminds me to go back to writing my DSL how-to based on experiences with binex, which is currently on hold until RakuAST)

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense and was about what I suspected; very helpful to have confirmation.  "Basically the above compiles into this code: `infix:<~>( ｢a b c ｣, $thing.Str, ｢ d e f｣ )`".  That's the sort of code I was thinking about when I asked whether I could avoid stringifying `$thing` if it's a type under my control – after all, I _could_ theoretically write a `.Str` method that doesn't return a `Str`.  But now that you point out the way `infix:<~>` is being used, that path seems unlikely to work – if it does anything, it would probably just break interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

What happens here has little to do with quoting, and a lot to do with [context](https://docs.raku.org/language/contexts#index-entry-string_context). As @brad-gilbert has indicated, anything that goes passes through putting `~` in front, which is coercing the variable to a `String` context.

But that yields an answer to your second question:

> Would there be a way to do so if $a were a class I'd defined (and thus can write the Str method for) rather than a Bool?

Theoretically, something like this should work:

```
class A { 
    has Bool $.foo;
    method Str { $.foo }
};
my $a = A.new( :foo(True) );
say «a b $a».raku
```

Alas, this returns `«No such method 'WORDS_AUTODEREF' for invocant of type 'Bool'␤` so it probably needs a bit of work (or I might have bumped into some bug). So this is, for the time being, and for your precise example, a *nanswer*. As a matter of fact, only `Str`s have that method, so I think that for the time being, and unless you bother to create that specialized method for a class, it's difficult to do.