# How to check if named parameters are being passed within function body in Raku

Tags: raku, rakudo

I have this code with two functions, the second function has some **named** parameters with **default** values:

```raku
sub func1($x,$y) {
    # do something
}

sub some_func($x, $y , :$vel = 1, :$acceleration = 1/$vel) {
    # if  $vel and $acceleration both are not missing
    #    call func1($x, $y) 
    # else do something else
}
```

As we know the second function can be called in following ways:

`some_func($x, $y); #vel and acceleration are missing`

`some_func($x, $y, vel => 2, acceleration => 5); #vel and acceleration are not missing`

In second call, named parameters: `vel` and `acceleration` are passed. How can I check *within* the function **body** that these
two named parameters are being passed?

Readings:

[Keeping default values for nested named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66555706/keeping-default-values-for-nested-named-parameters)

https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature

[Why does constraining a Perl 6 named parameter to a definite value make it a required value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48166325/why-does-constraining-a-perl-6-named-parameter-to-a-definite-value-make-it-a-req)

Comment: Sounds like you need a multi sub https://stackoverflow.com/a/48168355/7270649

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, though – as far as I know – all of them involve changing `&some-func`'s definition (not just its body).

I'd probably do it like this: split the function into a [`multi`](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Multi-dispatch) with one candidate that handles the case where both arguments are passed.  You can do that by marking the named arguments as `required` for that candidate a `!`.  Here's how that would look:

```raku
multi some-func3($x, $y, :$vel!, :$acceleration!) {
        note "Both arguments passed"
}

multi some-func3($x, $y, :$vel = 1, :$acceleration = 1 ÷ $vel) {
        note "Do something else"
}
```

Or you could do it by dropping the default values from the function signature and then setting them in the body (this solution will likely look familiar to anyone used to a programming language that doesn't support default values).  Note that modifying `$vel` and `$acceleration` requires marking them as `is copy`.

```raku
sub some-func($x, $y, :$vel is copy, :$acceleration is copy) {
    if $vel.defined && $acceleration.defined {
        note "Both not missing"
    } else {
        $vel //= 1; 
        $acceleration //= 1 ÷ $vel;
        note "Do something else"
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to capture all of the arguments to `some-func` before assigning defaults and then to inspect the [`Capture`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Capture).  That might look like:

```raku
sub some-func2(|c ($x, $y, :$vel = 1, :$acceleration = 1 ÷ $vel)) {
    when c<vel> & c<acceleration> ~~ Any:D { note "Both args passed" }
    note "Do something else"
}
```

(Note that this approach gives slightly worse error messages when `some-func` is passed the wrong arguments)

Or you could give each default value a marker [`role`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/role) that you can test against in the function body:

```raku
my role MyDefault {}
sub some-func5($x, $y, :$vel = 1 but MyDefault,
                       :$acceleration = (1 ÷ $vel) but MyDefault) {
    when $vel | $acceleration ~~ MyDefault { note "Do something else"}
    note "Both args passed"
}
```

Or, a slight variant of the above: use a string literal to auto-generate a role rather than defining one manually.  This is slightly less typesafe – it doesn't protect against typos in the role name – but is also a bit more concise.

```raku
sub some-func($x, $y, :$vel = 1 but 'default',
                      :$acceleration = (1 ÷ $vel) but 'default') {
    when $vel | $acceleration eq 'default' { note "Do something else"}
    note "Both args passed"
}
```

Like I said, I'd go with the `multi`.  But I hope that seeing several different ways helps you think about the problem – and maybe even teaches a bit of more advanced Raku syntax.

Comment: Great answer! "This is slightly less typesafe – it doesn't protect against typos in the role name." It also doesn't protect against `some-func 42, 99, vel => 'default'`. (That may of course be a feature in some scenarios.) Conversely, in some scenarios `:$vel = 1 but my role default {}, :$acceleration = (1 ÷ $vel) but default` in the signature and `if $vel | $acceleration ~~ default` in the body is slightly *better* because the `default` role is constrained to the routine body, even more constrained than putting the `my role default {}` *outside* the routine. Different ways helps you think! 

Comment: Thank you @codesections. Very elaborate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** For most use cases I'd go with @codesections' answer. But someone might appreciate this approach, which uses `wrap`.

Leave the existing `some_func` definition completely as is. Then add code like this:

```
&some_func .wrap: sub (|args) {
    if args<vel acceleration> .all { func1 |args.list }
    else { nextsame }
}
```

Job done.

## Discussion

> How can I check *within* the function **body** that these two named parameters are being passed?

You can do pretty much anything you want to do if you're willing to abuse Raku's slang capabilities to change the language.

But short of that, as far as I know you either need to change `&some-func`'s definition, or leave it unchanged. @codesections showed some ways to change it. Here I show new code you can add to produce a similar effect:

Add this code:

```
&some_func .wrap: sub (|args) {
    if args<vel acceleration> .all { func1 |args.list }
    else { nextsame }
}
```

(See [`wrap`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/wrap), [`|args`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#prefix_%7C), [`<foo bar>`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#postcircumfix_%3C_%3E), [`.all`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/all), [`.list`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/list#type/Captureroutinemethod), [`nextsame`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/nextsame) for more info.)

Now you can call it like this:

```
some_func 42, 99;
some_func 42, 99, vel => 1;
some_func 42, 99, acceleration => 2;
some_func 42, 99, vel => 3, acceleration => 4;
```

And it'll work as you specified.